# Rails Duplicate entry 'xyz@gmail.com' for key 'index_users_on_email'

Tags: mysql, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, error-handling

I am new to Rails and i am trying to upload a users via CSV to my Rails app but i am getting an error. Duplicate entry 'xyz@gmail.com' for key 'index_users_on_email' i am not sure hoow to validate a duplicate entry in CSV please help.

This is my code:

```
def self.import_students(school, file)

    params = {
      "students_attributes" => {}
    }


    row_count = 1
    users_count = 0
    errors = []

    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|

      row_count += 1
      standard = Standard.where(name: row["Standard"]).first

      fields = ['Name', 'Email', 'Gender', 'Standard', 'Section']
      fields.each do |field|
        if row[field].blank?
          errors << {
            row: row_count,
            message: "can't be empty",
            column: field
          }
        end
      end
      if standard.blank?
        errors << {
          row: row_count,
          message: "Invalid Standard #{row['Standard']} - Not found",
          column: "Standard"
        }
      end

      section = school.sections.where(standard_id: standard.id, name: row["Section"]).first
      section_id = section.blank? ? nil : section.id
      if section_id.blank?
        errors << {
          row: row_count,
          message: "Invalid Section #{row['Section']} - Not found",
          column: "Section"
        }
      end
      user_params = {
        name: row["Name"],
        email: row["Email"],
        role: User::ROLE_STUDENT,
        gender: row['Gender'].to_s.downcase == "male",
        studies_attributes: {

          "0" => {
            section_id: section_id,
            academic_year_id: school.academic_year.id,
            roll_no: row["Roll"].to_i,
          }
        }
      }
      params['students_attributes'][users_count] = user_params
      users_count += 1

    end

    return {
      params: params,
      errors: errors
    }

  end
```

My import action in controller:

```
def import
      if params[:students_file].present?
        output = User.import_students(@school, params[:students_file])
      elsif params[:teachers_file].present?
        output = User.import_teachers(@school, params[:teachers_file])
      end


      if output[:errors].blank?
        return output[:params]
      else
        @errors = output[:errors]
        respond_to do |format|
          @action_name = default_action.to_s
          format.html { render action: @action_name }
        end

        return false
      end

    end





 def update
    if (params[:students_file].present?
      output = import
      if output
        build_params = output
      else
        return
      end
    else
      build_params = school_params
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @school.update(build_params)
        format.html { default_redirect }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        @action_name = default_action.to_s
        format.html { render action: @action_name }
        format.json { render json: @school.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Please post the code where you process the `params` hash.

Comment: @colinm actually the code is working fine if in case i am taking the unique email address, in in case i am giving the same email in my CSV file code breaks

Comment: I am not sure how to validates the uniqueness in csv

Comment: The error message you're seeing is generated by the database after Active Record tries to insert a row (in this case, a User record). Your CSV code does not create any User records. The problem is likely where you're processing the `params` hash, and that's also where you would deal with uniqueness.

Comment: @colinm i have updated my code above please have a look

Comment: how to use error handler begin and raise ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a array email_count and store the email field in email_count to check for the duplicate entries. Even i have added the code for the for if in case email already exist in the database.

Add this piece of code to your code, declare the **email_count =[]** at the top.

```
if email_count.include? row["Email"]
  errors << {
    row: row_count,
    message: "Duplicate Entry",
    column: "Email"
  }
end

email_count << row["Email"]
```

I have updated your above code

```
def self.import_students(school, file)

    params = {
      "students_attributes" => {}
    }

    email_count = []
    row_count = 1
    users_count = 0
    errors = []

    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|

      row_count += 1
      standard = Standard.where(name: row["Standard"]).first

      fields = ['Name', 'Email', 'Gender', 'Standard', 'Section']
      fields.each do |field|
        if row[field].blank?
          errors << {
            row: row_count,
            message: "can't be empty",
            column: field
          }
        end
      end
      if User.where(:email => row["Email"]).exists?
        errors << {
          row: row_count,
          message: "Email already taken",
          column: "Email"
        }
      end
      if standard.blank?
        errors << {
          row: row_count,
          message: "Invalid Standard #{row['Standard']} - Not found",
          column: "Standard"
        }
      end

      section = school.sections.where(standard_id: standard.id, name: row["Section"]).first
      section_id = section.blank? ? nil : section.id
      if section_id.blank?
        errors << {
          row: row_count,
          message: "Invalid Section #{row['Section']} - Not found",
          column: "Section"
        }
      end
      # debugger
      if email_count.include? row["Email"]
        errors << {
          row: row_count,
          message: "Duplicate Entry",
          column: "Email"
        }
      end
      email_count << row["Email"]
      # debugger
      user_params = {
        name: row["Name"],
        email: row["Email"],
        role: User::ROLE_STUDENT,
        gender: row['Gender'].to_s.downcase == "male",
        studies_attributes: {

          "0" => {
            section_id: section_id,
            academic_year_id: school.academic_year.id,
            roll_no: row["Roll"].to_i,
          }
        }
      }
      # debugger
      params['students_attributes'][users_count] = user_params
      # debugger
      users_count += 1

    end

    return {
      params: params,
      errors: errors
    }

  end
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue isn't your CSV. It sounds like the issue is you have a hash somewhere that's attempting to create two key-value pairs using the same key, in this case the same email address. You have a few options:

1. Require all emails in CSV to be unique
2. Change keys from emails to something that is truly unique such as user_id or something similar
3. Manually change duplicate email addresses by tacking on an identifier onto the end (ex. email_1, email_2, etc) I would not recommend this one but it's your choice.